# Change global vars in Lua from C 'globally'

Tags: c, lua, lua-table

Can you change the value of a global field in an entire .lua-file if you re-set this global field from C ?

this could be the lua-file:

```
GlobalVar   = 123      

Table1 = {ID = 1,   Val = GlobalVar}      -- Val = 123
```

Now if I call via Lua's C-API...

```
luaL_loadfile(lua, "lua-file" ...

lua_pushstring(lua, "321");
lua_setglobal(lua, "GlobalVar");
```

this only changes "GlobalVar" to *321* **but not** "Val" from "Table1".

It seems like the **initial** value of GlobalVar is *copied* to Table1 when the .lua-file is loaded for the first time.

Is there a way to update the entire lua-file?

Comment: As you already noticed `GlobalVar` is copied because it's a number value (value-copy, not reference-copy). To update your table entry too, you have to do it manually or store your value in a table which serves as pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Youka has described in a comment, you can't do this because the value is copied at the time you initialize `Table1`.  If what you're doing is setting the globals, then running the lua code once, you can conditionally initialize the globals in the Lua file:

```
if GlobalVar == nil then GlobalVar = 123 end

Table1 = {ID = 1,   Val = GlobalVar}      -- Val = 123
```

This gives you a chance to establish the global first from C with `lua_setglobal`, or accept the default.

Comment: So you mean, I call 'lua_setglobal(..' and 'luaL_loadfile(..' *afterwards* ?